# Linq - Creating Expression<T1> from Expression<T2>

Tags: c#, linq, predicate, linq-expressions

I have a predicate `Expression<Func<T1, bool>>`

I need to use it as a predicate `Expression<Func<T2, bool>>` using the `T1` property of `T2` I was trying to think about several approches, probably using `Expression.Invoke` but couln;t get my head around it.

For reference:

```
class T2 {
  public T1 T1;
}
```

And

```
Expression<Func<T1, bool>> ConvertPredicates(Expression<Func<T2, bool>> predicate) {
  //what to do here...
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to find the solution with normal lambdas before you think about expression trees.

You have a predicate

```
Func<T1, bool> p1
```

and want a predicate

```
Func<T2, bool> p2 = (x => p1(x.T1));
```

You can build this as an expression tree as follows:

```
Expression<Func<T2, bool>> Convert(Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "x");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(predicate, Expression.PropertyOrField(x, "T1")), x);
}
```