# Create Linq Expressions <T2,T1,bool> from <T1,T2,bool>

Tags: c#, linq, associations, predicate, linq-expressions

I would like to prevent duplicating the same predicate logic used for both side of joins/associations in ORMs. Should I:

1) use `Func<T1, T2, bool>` and use extension methods to get expressions:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> ExpressionFuncT1T2<T1, T2>(this Func<T1, T2, bool> func) => (t1, t2) => func(t1, t2);

public static Expression<Func<T2, T1, bool>> ExpressionFuncT2T1<T1, T2>(this Func<T1, T2, bool> func) => (t1, t2) => func(t2, t1);
```

or

2) use `Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>>` for one side and convert it to `Expression<Func<T2, T1, bool>>` like something below based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626965/linq-creating-expressiont1-from-expressiont2) answer:

```
public static Expression<Func<T2, T1, bool>> WhatToCallThis<T1,T2>(
         this Expression<Func<T1, T2, bool>> predicate) {

      var t1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t1");
      var t2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2), "t2");
      return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, T1, bool>>(
          Expression.Invoke(predicate, 
          Expression.PropertyOrField(t2, "T1"), 
          Expression.PropertyOrField(t1, "T2")
          ), t2, t1);
    }
```

Also what would you name this method?

Comment: Since you are passing in `predicate` that is an `Expression<Func<T1,T2,bool>>` what are you gaining by calling `WhatToCallThis`?

Comment: Start by trying both of those and even seeing if they work.  Then decide which one you like better, if you still have a decision left.

Comment: @NetMage: For some ORM's I use I need to call the method with T1 as first argument and then T2 as first argument on other side of association.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all 3 methods below work, but which would be the best to use performance wise?

SwapParameters1 using **Expression.Lambda**:

```
public static Expression<Func<T2, T1, TResult>> SwapParameters1<T1, T2, TResult>
  (this Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> exprFunc)
  => Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, T1, TResult>>(exprFunc.Body
                                            , exprFunc.Parameters[1]
                                            , exprFunc.Parameters[0]);
```

SwapParameters2 using **.Compile():**

```
public static Expression<Func<T2, T1, TResult>> SwapParameters2<T1, T2, TResult>
  (this Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> exprFunc)
  => (t1, t2) => exprFunc.Compile()(t2, t1);
```

SwapParameters3 using an **ExpressionVisitor** to replace parameters (this [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154906/how-to-modify-type-parameter-of-expressionfunc-bool) question helped):

```
public static Expression<Func<T2, T1, TResult>> SwapParameters3<T1, T2, TResult>
  (this Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> exprFunc) {
  var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1));
  var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2));
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, T1, TResult>>(exprFunc.Body
    .Replace(exprFunc.Parameters[0], param1)
    .Replace(exprFunc.Parameters[1], param2)
    , param1, param2);
}

public static Expression<Func<TNewParam, TResult>> ReplaceParameter<TNewParam, TOldParam, TResult>
  (this Expression<Func<TOldParam, TResult>> expression)
  where TNewParam : TOldParam {
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TNewParam));
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<TNewParam, TResult>>(
    expression.Body.Replace(expression.Parameters[0], param)
    , param);
}

public class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor {
  private readonly Expression from, to;
  public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to) {
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
  }

  public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression, Expression searchExpression, Expression replaceExpression)
  => new ReplaceVisitor(searchExpression, replaceExpression).Visit(expression);
```

I am leaning towards using SwapParameters1.